# scrapy ImagesPipeline when image item does not exist

Tags: scrapy

In item.py, i defined image filed. In settings.py, IMAGES_URLS_FIELD,IMAGES_STORE are also defined.

In spider.py, image is got in parse function. It works fine when there is valid image url. The problem is the image field might be None. It will get can not request none error in the pipelines.py.

i try to set a default url value for image field, but it does not work.

Here is my piplelines:

```
def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
     yield Request(item["image"])

def item_completed(self, results, item, info):
    image_paths = [x['path'] for ok, x in results if ok]
    if not image_paths:
        raise DropItem("Item contains no images")
    item['image'] = image_paths
    return item
```

How to set default value for image field when it is empty?